# Windows batch script output not written to log

Tags: oracle, batch-file, cmd, tee, impdp

We have this Windows batch script:

```
call commands/do-work.cmd | tee my.log
```

The do-work.cmd includes

```
impdp user/pw@db directory=mydir dumpfile=my.dmp logfile=logdir:imp.log schemas=a,b,c,c parallel=6

(
echo my.sql
echo exit
) | sqlplus user/pw@db

call mvn clean install
```

Of these commands the output from sqlplus and mvn is written to my.log but the output of impdp is not. How can I get impdp output into my.log?

Tried using "call" ahead of impdp but the impdp command choked for some reason...  complaining about log not found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IMPDP in order to test it how it works. So, "logfile=logdir:imp.log" generates a imp.log file, right? you want the content of this file inside of MY.LOG?
Try:

TYPE imp.log >> my.log

If IMPDP write the info in the console you can try adding ">> my.log" at the end of the command line instead.